# Initial value of BehaviorSubject in a service getted from HTTP API

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

in a service I have this BehaviorSubject, and I try to get the default value using a get HTTP request:

```
defaultItems!: ColumnsToFilterWithItems[];
columnsToFilterWithItemsBehaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<ColumnsToFilterWithItems[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ColumnsToFilterWithItems[]>(this.defaultItems);
constructor() {
    this.getColumnsToFilterWithItems().subscribe(columnsToFilterWithItems => {
      this.defaultItems = columnsToFilterWithItems  }) // get default data by calling a get http method
  }
```

In the component when I subscribe to the behavior subject (after using asObservable() method) in the ngOnInit method i can't get the default data  and I have this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next
```

When I hard code the default value (defaultItems), it works well.
When I can call the getColumnsToFilterWithItems method to avoid this error?
Thank you.

Comment: try moving the instance creation of behavior subject to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing to the behaviour subject wrongly.

Try like this

```
this.getColumnsToFilterWithItems.subscribe(columnsToFilterWithItems => {
  this.defaultItems = columnsToFilterWithItems  
}) // get default data by calling a get http method
```

Incase if you're trying to get data from API use like this

```
getColumnsToFilterWithItems(){
  return "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
}
```